# How can I set text to be copied to clipboard when image is copied?

Tags: javascript, html, image, copy-paste, alt

I am building a web page and have run into something that would be nice to be able to do; set text to be copied to the clipboard when someone tries to copy an image, probably the same as the alt text. Is there any way with javascript/html that this can be done? If so, please explain.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Basically, I want to let my users highlight the image, press control-c, and then have the alt text stored in their clipboard.

Comment: Are you looking to just copy the alt text?  Or HTML that contains the image and some sort of caption with it?

Comment: Just to copy the alt text when someone highlights the image and copies it would be great.

Comment: Normally no images get copied on pressing cttl + c when hovered on a image. So what you means by highlighted?

Comment: I think only IE supports `oncopy` for images and you'd probably need flash for the copying to clipboard part

Comment: @McLosysCreative Hightlight as in clicking down and dragging over it, the way you would copy text.

Comment: @Musa Well, in that case probably isn't even worth trying to put it in.

Answer (score 3):

add attribute `alt="text"` to your image

example:

```html
<img alt="" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/14.0.2/72x72/1f1eb-1f1f7.png">
```

Answer (score 2):

This *is* possible as Twitch.tv does this when copying emote images in chat.  The trick is to use the [`copy` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event).

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');
parent.addEventListener('copy', event => {
  let selection = document.getSelection(),
    range = selection.getRangeAt(0),
    contents = range.cloneContents(),
    copiedText = '';

  for (let node of contents.childNodes.values()) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
      // text node
      copiedText += node.textContent;
    } else if (node.nodeType === 1 && node.nodeName === 'IMG') {
      copiedText += node.dataset.copyText;
    }
  }

  event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', copiedText);
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(`Text copied: '${copiedText}'`);
});
```

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

#parent,
#pasteHere {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.icon {
  width: 32px;
}

#pasteHere {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  background: #E7E7E7;
}
```

```html
<p>Copy the line below:</p>

<div id="parent">
  Some text <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=f13ebeedfa9e" class="icon" data-copy-text="foo" /> some more text <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=f13ebeedfa9e"
    class="icon" data-copy-text="bar" />
</div>

<div id="pasteHere" contenteditable>Paste here!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. If you could hook keyboard events through the browser, that'd be a tremendous security issue. You could capture keystrokes and send them to a web service in a few lines of code, which would ruin some lives pretty easily.

You may be able to detect a mouse down event using onmousedown by attaching it to the image in some fashion and store that alt-text in a hidden field or cookie and `DoSomething()` from there.

Comment: Okay, I'm not terribly surprised by that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen services such as [tynt](http://www.tynt.com/) do something like this. [2065880 Javascript: Hijack Copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065880/javascript-hijack-copy) talks about the techniques, as does [1203082 Injecting text when content is copied from Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203082/injecting-text-when-content-is-copied-from-web-page)

Comment: Thank you. I'll consider this as an option, but at this point it looks like I probably will just give up.